# Audio is scratchy on UX390UA (asus) w/ Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: pulseaudio, asus, 16.10

The audio is scratchy on my new ASUS UX390UA

I have tried everything I could find but nothing seems to fix the problem.
I also tried with headphones and am not getting any sound there. The laptop speakers have sound but its very scratchy.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
sudo restart
```

This fixed the scratchy audio for me. I had to change the sound settings to use `Audio Surround 4.0 output` using `pavucontrol`

This however did not fix headphones. If I plugin headphones audio is still coming out of the laptop speakers.

Comment: This actually made things worse for me. :/ I'm using a UX390UA-77DHDAB1.

Comment: `model=auto` made it better, tho!

Comment: Installing the intel microcode proprietary drivers also helped. Check out https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingGuide#Ae_.28.28Make_NVIDIA_HDMI_Audio_work.29

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common
```

and change this section:

```
[Element PCM]
switch = mute
volume = merge
override-map.1 = all
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right
```

Into this:

```
[Element Master]
switch = mute
volume = ignore


[Element PCM]
switch = mute
volume = merge
override-map.1 = all
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right


[Element LFE]
switch = mute
volume = ignore
```

save (with Ctrl+x) and reboot

Source: [Ubuntu 16.10 on Asus Zenbook 3 UX390 - Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2340639&p=13581528#post13581528)